# How do I get text data from OAuth callback?

Tags: java, oauth, box-api

I am having an issue with the response I am getting when I try to get the authorization code I need to start the authenticated client.  The response appears (at least to me) to be some sort of binary data, (with one or two recognizable string fragments in it), but I have no idea how to deal with it.  The code from the API's 'hello world' program seems to be parsing this data as a string, but when I try it, it fails because it isn't in the expected format.

This is adapted from the 'Hello World' program (from the box api github wiki) found [here](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2/wiki/HelloWorld) in order to show what the problem appears to be.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class HelloBox {
    public static final int socket_port = 4000;
    public static final String
        redirect_uri = "https://localhost:" + socket_port,
        client_id = /* [...] */, client_secret = /* [...] */;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create(
            "https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?" +
            "response_type=code" +
            "&client_id=" + client_id +
            "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri));

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socket_port);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));

        for(int idx = 0; idx < 4; idx++){
            String line = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            out.println(line);
        }

        //[... closing all the streams and sockets ...]
    }
}
```

All the lines after the fourth are just `null`, so that is why I stopped it after four lines.

You can see the result in my `output.txt` file [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7231cQnKsDQRHJiS3V5amkzZXc/edit?usp=sharing).  My computer refuses to paste the string, so I couldn't include it itself in the question.  I have tried examining the output with a hex editor, but I couldn't see any obvious pattern to it. (Bursts of stuff separated by occasional `NULL`?)

Myriad Google searches turned up nothing that appears to be of relevance for this issue, and neither the Javadoc nor the API tutorials were helpful here, either.

How can I deal with this issue?  If my code is wrong, please tell me how I can correct it.

EDIT:
So I tried replacing the `socket` and `serverSocket` with

```
SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(socket_port);
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
```

but now I am getting
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common` at the line where it first tries to read from the stream.

Comment: I suspect that what you are seeing is what's being sent.  That is, you are reading in plaintext, but the client is sending you encrypted text (https).

Comment: @RussellUhl I am navigating the user to a password sign-in thing at the listed URL.  I don't really know how it works, but the thing with the server socket is what the example code does.

Comment: @RussellUhl So how would I fix the problem, if that's what it is?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't really know, other than it probably involves an `SSLServerSocket`.  It might be as simple as replacing your serversocket with its cousin, but it might not.  Give it a try, see what happens.  Also, try pointing to some random URL that DOESN'T use https, and see if the returned info is more readable.

Comment: @RussellUhl Ok, I tried that, but I am having some more problems with it.

Comment: yea ok, I didn't think it would be that simple.  Worth a shot though.  I can attempt to play around with this when I get home, provided work doesn't keep me late and paperwork doesn't attack me.

Comment: I think all you need to do is change your callback URL in line 8 to 'http  ://localhost' instead of 'https ://localhost'

Comment: @PlatformBoxer thanks, that worked.  Now my only problems are with `ClassDefNotFoundException`s and stuff.